# Marking data between columns with specified content in Talend

Tags: rows, talend

I have certain data as in following format:

> Start-Data
>
> India|23|8.001|12/09/2013
>
> UK|22|4.001|12/10/2013
>
> USA|13|4.001|12/08/2013
>
> End-Data
>
> Start-Data
>
> Asia|123|8.001|22/09/2013
>
> E|22|4.001|12/10/2013
>
> USA|13|4.001|15/08/2013
>
> End-Data

There can be any 'n' number of rows before 1st Start-Data and last End-Data in the file. I want to ignore those rows and only take rows between 1st Start-Data and last End-Data. How do I get it?

I am trying to achieve it using tStandardizeRow.

Answer (score 0):

considering pipe is the delimiter here and number of columns for all other row except start-data and end-data is consistent...then you can do something like below
tFileInputDelimited-->tfilterRow--.Finaloutput/dboutput component where you want to insert/process data.

in tFileInputDelimited schema i would define it like as below
column1, column2, column3, column4...delimeter | and end of line by \n.

now in tFilterRow i would apply filter condition as column1 is not equal to Start-Data and End Data....

at high level we are reading all lines, but then filtering using tfilterrow..and since we have used end of line so your end-data and start-data would be read but as column1 value for these lines...
you also would have to allow nullable for all columns...

Comment: That would only get the start-data and end-data lines and not the actual data.

Comment: not sure..as it should ideally read all 10 lines in above example and out of these 4 lines would have column1 value as start-data and end-data and would be blocked by filter...what i have suggested is to read the file as input delimited file using input component and then filter rows inside talend..i am assuming here that start-data and end-data are actual rows in the file with data text as start data and end data..